# How to include a list of variables in a Spinbox in Python Tkinter

Tags: python, list, tkinter

I'm trying to create a Spin-box using Tkinter in Python that contains days of the month (**strings**), yet only know how to include numbers in a range. e.g.; `from_ = 1900, to = 2016`.

How can I include a list of strings in the spin box? do I need to create an actual **list?**

Here is the specific code:

```
w = StringVar()
Spinbox(root, from_ = 1900, to = 2017, textvariable = w, width = 5).place(x = 315, y = 60)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just pass a list of strings to the `values` option of the spinbox:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Spinbox
root = Tk()
months = ["January", "February", "March"]
spinbox = Spinbox(root, values=months)
spinbox.pack()
root.mainloop()
```